# Check if two enum values are the same in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

Is there a way to determine that two enums don't have the same *values*?

My team is using flux with multiple stores, each with their own set of actions, but all on the same dispatcher.  Each set of actions is an `enum`.  We could very easily convert these to `as const` constants, but I'm curious if I could leave them as enums.

This is what I have:

```ts
type CompositeEnum<
  T extends readonly Record<string, string | number>[],
  C extends Record<string, string | number> = {}
> =
  T['length'] extends 0
    ? Readonly<{ [K in keyof C]: C[K] }>
    : T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
      ? (keyof Head & keyof C) | (Head[keyof Head] & C[keyof C] & (number | string)) extends never
        ? Tail extends readonly Record<string, string | number>[]
          ? (
            & { [K in keyof C]: C[K] }
            & { [K in keyof Head]: Head[K] }
          ) extends infer Next
            ? Next extends Record<string, string | number>
              ? CompositeEnum<Tail, Next>
              : never
            : never
          : never
        : never
      : never;

function compositeEnum<
  T extends readonly Record<string, string | number>[]
>(...enums: T): CompositeEnum<T> {
  return Object.assign({}, ...enums);
}
```

This works for `as const` constants, but TypeScript treats each enum key as a distinct type.

```ts
enum Foo {
  foo = 'foo'
}

enum Bar {
  bar = 'foo'
}

type FooBar = CompositeEnum<[typeof Foo, typeof Bar]>;
/**
 * type FooBar = {
 *   readonly foo: Foo.foo;
 *   readonly bar: Bar.bar;
 * }
 */
```

Interestingly, if I directly check the types' values, it works.

```ts
type Never = typeof Foo[keyof typeof Foo] & typeof Bar[keyof typeof Bar] & string;
```

Ideas?  [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAzgS2BAogOwK4IA8AUFFACpQQAemOAJilAE4QCG9cOANiFAEoQAxnGb1CKYMzQ4A5gBook6XKgAfKPgQAjCMwB8AbQC680rCq0IDJoJFiJUmQqVPVGrboNQAvFADeAL7E+r7m5IYA5NzWssAAFpHGlnSMUAAM5mQA-ALsnDwghP5QhgDSUDJQANYQIHAAZrDGAFyw5cmB+llQbZQ0qUyGMg16UAAS+YoAdLMjY+RsaNzGPTlQABS19U2THFAAZDV1jbAAlOqbe-SG26fXyUcwtydNMI+bnmMays5nFwNrGkcBAAG56NZkKC5RbLFJApisDhcXh5eziX5yRSY2SXL4GEyQqHQzZE4mHAKlCpVO5vVrtMqdMnEo4lcqVHDHHYTfL064dKDBcnkgFWGwc0bMKAAOQGzKhuVltHh4rsogxbhcOLxBC83WFBpJ8CQqAw2C0hFh3EUSuA+sN5LaIPBzHlZCdYIhDt6mk9rsNHpdkMDegA3MRiA08DghMA0FwoCITehMLgCJaVWkkQVUWqHDjsZqdTo9EZjPoNrNptYCCg+mc2sbkCnzenyKF-OZWMA8MxOQB5bQAK2EwGmbBQ6FkOA2QRmsxrCBQZ3DwWIi6gADE4HAAuYGjvfFBIge4JFiIFw+utFAAEJsKWdsjaB9HyIv5jny8Rjf3gBee7PmwAF+O+wGRGYZCnm+p5flev7AQATIBUAviBx6wReEagJAW47v+yF+E2pqphahg4RApzbnAigUacBHlleIg4JIUCnmhhGJogzZmmmCAbNRigESuQA)

Comment: Sadly, Typescript enums are nominal, not structural. For example: `type A = Foo.foo extends Bar.bar ? true : false` is `false`. So if you are trying to compare them structurally, this is going to be hard. I don't have answer except to say that I've always found typescript enums to be fairly cumbersome and full of odd pitfalls, and I have learned to avoid them, generally.

Comment: That is by design. Imagine you had two enums without explicit values, one named Apples and the other Oranges. Apples.BIG and Oranges.BIG, if both defined as the first key, would both equal 0, but that doesn't mean that they should compare equal.